# Running node express application with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I've created a simple node express application with typescript support. There is the main *index.tsx* file:

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import GetDta from './src/discogs_api/services'

const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.get('/OAuth', (req, res) => {
    res.send('OAuth\'ing!...')
    GetDta()
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`CORS Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Now when I'd like to run the app using:

```
npx nodemon -e tsx index.tsx
```

i get an error:`Cannot use import statement outside a module.`

What's more odd when i change the file extension to just *ts* i run without any problems. Why can't i use the *tsx* extension?

Comment: Why would you use tsx? It's not JSX.

Comment: @Keimeno  Why not? Its' also allowed extension for typescripe'd node files. And sorry, but please don't answer making a new question but try to answer if You can please.

Comment: You use `.tsx` files when working with React and Typescript. For any other app, you would use `.ts` files

Comment: Your error is either coming from what Keimeno says or it's emanating from src/discogs_api/services. Could you paste the full error message. And your response to Keimeno is kind of rude, he's pointing you in the right direction.